# Retrieve chemical synonyms from Chemspider with R

Tags: xml, r, web-scraping

My current R script parses the chemical synonym names from http://www.chemspider.com based on a given Chemspider id, in this case for "Irganox 1076" (code taken from [Scraping experimentally measured physicochemical properties and synonyms from Chemspider in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21713278/scraping-experimentally-measured-physicochemical-properties-and-synonyms-from-ch)):

```
library(XML)
csid     <- "15539" 
url      <- paste0("http://www.chemspider.com/Chemical-Structure.",csid,".html")
doc      <- htmlTreeParse(url,useInternal=T)
synNodes <- getNodeSet(doc,'//div[@id="synonymsTab"]/div/div/div/p[@class="syn"]')
synonyms <- sapply(synNodes,function(x)xmlValue(getNodeSet(x,"./strong")[[1]]))
synonyms
```

Result:

```
[1] "3-[4-Hydroxy-3,5-bis(2-mÃ©thyl-2-propanyl)phÃ©nyl]propanoate d'octadÃ©cyle"    "benzenepropanoic acid, 3,5-bis(1,1-dimethylethyl)-4-hydroxy-, octadecyl ester"
 [3] "Octadecyl 3-(3,5-di-tert-butyl-4-hydroxyphenyl)propanoate"                     "Octadecyl 3-(3,5-di-tert-butyl-4-hydroxyphenyl)propionate"                    
 [5] "Octadecyl 3,5-di-t-butyl-4-hydroxyhydrocinnamate"                              "Octadecyl 3,5-di-tert-butyl-4-hydroxyhydrocinnamate"                          
 [7] "octadecyl 3-[3,5-bis(tert-butyl)-4-hydroxyphenyl]propanoate"                   "Octadecyl 3-[4-hydroxy-3,5-bis(2-methyl-2-propanyl)phenyl]propanoate"         
 [9] "Octadecyl-3-(3,5-di-tert.butyl-4-hydroxyphenyl)-propionate"                    "Octadecyl-3-[4-hydroxy-3,5-bis(2-methyl-2-propanyl)phenyl]propanoat"
```

**Problem:**
Unfortunately the script just shows the initial results from Chemspider. The [http://www.chemspider.com](http://www.chemspider.com/Chemical-Structure.15539.html) site shows an extended lists with many more synonyms once you manually click the "more..." button.

**Question:**
How can I modify the script so that the results of the script include the extended list of synonyms.

Comment: You might want to look into using an official [Chemspider API](http://www.chemspider.com/aboutservices.aspx) rather than trying to scrape pages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to work reasonably well

```
library(XML)
csid     <- "15539" 
url      <- paste0("http://www.chemspider.com/Chemical-Structure.",csid,".html")
doc      <- htmlTreeParse(url,useInternal=T)
synNodes <- getNodeSet(doc,'//div[@id="synonymsTab"]//p[@class="syn"]')
synonyms <- sapply(synNodes,function(x)xmlValue(getNodeSet(x,"./*[1]")[[1]]))
```

Comment: +1 for the xpath. As a side not @user2030503: The R way would probably be `xpathSApply` in the veins of `xpathSApply(doc, '//div[@id="synonymsTab"]//p[@class="syn"]/*[1]', xmlValue)`.

Answer (score 1):

sorry, not very familiar with R, but in order to extract any information from ChemSpider it's much better to use REST API then parsing web pages: http://parts.chemspider.com/json.ashx

For example, in order to get all synonyms associated with Aspirin you can do this: http://parts.chemspider.com/JSON.ashx?op=GetRecordsAsCompounds&csids[0]=2157&serfilter=Compound[Synonyms] or this http://parts.chemspider.com/JSON.ashx?op=GetRecordsAsCompounds&csids[0]=2157 in order to get all information about specified compound(s).

Comment: Hi @Alex. Do you know what the difference between this API (with "parts") and the other API that ChemSpider has the link on its website? It does not require token. Also, you seem like the only one I could find so far to know this API...

Comment: "Parts" API is free to use, but as I know is not very well supported right now